# iOS Parse GeoPoints & MapBox Shapes

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mapbox

So i am wondering how to go about retrieving Parse coordinates and drawing a shape using MapBox.

I can retrieve the coordinates and plot them individually (using [PARSE](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo/iOS)) on a map fine:

> ```
> PFQuery *locationQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Location"];
> [locationQuery whereKeyExists:@"location"];
> locationQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
> [locationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
>     if (!error) {
>         // The find succeeded.
>         NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
>         NSLog(@"Object is %@ and %@", [objects objectAtIndex:0],[objects objectAtIndex:1]);
>
>         for (PFObject *gp in objects) {
>
>             //How to get PFGeoPoint and then a location out of an object
>             PFGeoPoint *location = [gp objectForKey:@"location"];
>
>             NSLog(@"Hi there my name is: %f", location.latitude);
>
>             CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
>
>             //This is how to populate the data with a title
>             NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", gp.createdAt];
>
>             RMPointAnnotation *annotation3 = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView coordinate:coordinate andTitle:title];
>             [mapView addAnnotation:annotation3];
>
>         }
>
>     } else {
>         // Log details of the failure
>         NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
>     }
> }];
> ```

Adding a shape to a map (using [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/drawing-shape/)) is doable as well:

> ```
> //Line for streets location arrays, etc MapBox
>     NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.980852 longitude:151.072498],
>                           [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.981769 longitude:151.072300],
>                           [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.982018 longitude:151.072257],
>                           [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.982187 longitude:151.072225], nil, nil];
>
>     RMAnnotation *annoation43 = [[RMAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView coordinate:((CLLocation *)[locations
> ```
>
> objectAtIndex:0]).coordinate andTitle:@"Hola biatches!"];
>
> ```
>     annoation43.userInfo = locations;
>     [annoation43 setBoundingBoxFromLocations:locations];
>     [mapView addAnnotation:annoation43];
>     NSLog(@"It is working Dora!");
>
> -(RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapViewer layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation {
>
>     if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation)
>         return nil;
>
>     RMShape *shape = [[RMShape alloc] initWithView:mapView];
>
>     //Line dashes and colours and widths, etc
>     shape.lineColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
>     shape.lineWidth = 4.0;
>     shape.scaleLineWidth = YES;
>     shape.scaleLineDash = YES;
>     shape.lineDashLengths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4], [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], nil];
>     shape.lineDashPhase = 3.0f;
>
>
>
>     for (CLLocation *location in (NSArray *)annotation.userInfo)
>         [shape addLineToCoordinate:location.coordinate];
>
>     return shape;
>
>
> }
> ```

I am wondering how i would get MapBox to draw a shape from these coordinates? I have had a few attempts and am getting nowhere so someone with a better mind than i would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information let me know.

Comment: So I am leaning towards it being an issue with GeoPoints and CLLocation conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - my solution i was attempting was fine - i was initialising the array WITHIN the loop and so it was recreating the array each time and so was overwriting each new coordinate and trying to draw a shape using only one coordinate.

```
PFQuery *locationQuery2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Location"];
    [locationQuery2 whereKeyExists:@"location"];
    locationQuery2.limit = 4;
    locationQuery2.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
    [locationQuery2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
            NSLog(@"Object is %@ and %@", [objects objectAtIndex:0],[objects objectAtIndex:1]);
            NSMutableArray *locations = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] mutableCopy];

            for (PFObject *gp in objects) {

                //How to get PFGeoPoint and then a location out of an object
                PFGeoPoint *location = [gp objectForKey:@"location"];

                NSLog(@"Hi there my name is not: %f", location.latitude);

                CLLocation *coordinate = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude];

                //Line for streets location arrays, etc MapBox
                [locations addObject:coordinate];

                RMAnnotation *annoation43 = [[RMAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView coordinate:((CLLocation *)[locations objectAtIndex:0]).coordinate andTitle:@"Hola biatches!"];

                annoation43.userInfo = locations;
                [annoation43 setBoundingBoxFromLocations:locations];
                [mapView addAnnotation:annoation43];
                NSLog(@"It is working Dora!");


                NSLog(@"Yeah its is: %@", locations);
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```