# Mapbox Overlapping Circles

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, turfjs

Does anyone know a way to make overlapping circles in mapbox show the same color and only have the border around the outer edge display?

I have this:
[image]

And I made this in photoshop for what I want:
[image]

Comment: This looks like it would be a fun ( and challenging) problem to solve. Have you got a link to a sample map?

Comment: You may want to start with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056782/ios-parse-geopoints-mapbox-shapes and this link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35407512/5403120). If you create GeoJSON circles around your points with [Leaflet Geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy), then perform a union on them with [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/), you will have a single border around all the overlapping circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't think there is a way to style all the circles to show their group outline, you can achieve the effect you want by creating a union of all the circle geometries and applying your style to that. Unfortunately, Leaflet's [`L.circle` class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) offers no way to access a circle's geometry beyond the center point, and to perform a union, you need the path of the circle itself. Fortunately, there is [Leaflet Geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy) and its `LGeo.circle` class, which produces circular polygons with a given radius and number of segments. Once you have these polygon representations of your circles, you can use [`turf.union`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_union.html) to produce the outline you want.

Say you are starting with a layer of points called `pointLayer` (this can be a `L.geoJson`, `L.mapbox.featureLayer`, or any other class that inherits the [`.eachLayer` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer)). You can then iterate over the features, creating a circular polygon for each of them and adding it to a temporary layer group, like this:

```js
var circleLayer = L.layerGroup();
var radius = 5000
var opts = {
  parts: 144
};
pointLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  LGeo.circle(layer.getLatLng(), radius, opts).addTo(circleLayer);
});
```

where `radius` is in meters and the `parts` option is the number of segments you want your polygons to have. Next, use the `.getLayers` method to get an array of all the layers in the temporary group, then iterate over that to create a union of all the features:

```js
var circleUnion = unify(circleLayer.getLayers()).addTo(map);

function unify(polyList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < polyList.length; ++i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      var unionTemp = polyList[i].toGeoJSON();
    } else {
      unionTemp = turf.union(unionTemp, polyList[i].toGeoJSON());
    }
  }
  return L.geoJson(unionTemp, {style: unionStyle});
}
```

where `unionStyle` is whatever style you want to apply to your newly-combined circles. Here is an example fiddle showing all this with some random data:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/L2d626hn/

Comment: Thanks Nathan.  I researched your comment and got it to work.  I was going to message you to just put that as the answer but you beat me to it.  Thanks again for pointing out geodesy.

Comment: Hey Nathan, thanks. I wanted to use this library in react.js with a syntax like **import LGeo from 'leaflet-geodesy'** but I cannot do this. Also, unable to find any example. Could someone please help?